# Проблема v-model и axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

Столкнулся с проблемой.

имеется инпут:

```
<input type='checkbox' :value='category.id' v-model='checkedCategories' @change='changeEvent' @click='filteredCategories(category.id)>
```

**Дата:**

```
data() {
 return {
  checkedCategories: []
 }    
}
```

**JS:**

```
  filteredCategories(item) {

  axios.get('/', {
    params: {
      page: 1,
      per_page: 20,
      part_category_tags: this.checkedCategories
    }
  })
    .then((response) => {
      this.$store.commit(
        'showFilteredCategories',
        response.data.items
      );
    });
  }
```

**vuex**

```
showFilteredCategories(state, payload) {
  state.filteredCategories = payload;
}
```

При запросе, отсылается только `page` и `per_page`, не записывая массив. (полагаю, из-за реактивность). Инпутов на странице много, если кликнуть по 2му, запрос отправляется с `id` первого кликнутого. (массив в axios как будто отстает на 1 шаг)
Что нужно изменить/добавить?

Comment: добавьте, пожалуйста, весь код

Comment: @AleksandrBelous Дополнил, это всё, что относится к получению/обработке запроса

Comment: не пробовали проверять, чем является this.checkedCategories во время вызова метода?

Comment: @AleksandrBelous Если вызывать внутри метода то массив с длиной 0. 
Если в then, то с ид. В этом то и косяк, не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы он заполнялся ДО отправки запроса

Comment: @AleksandrBelous Получилось решить проблему, добавив сеттаймаут.

Comment: SetTimeout это не очень хорошо. Вместо него лучше использовать https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick